# Centering google-slides text

Tags: google-slides-api

I'm creating google slides from a csv upload via the browser. When I'm inserting text, how would I center that? They only show up on the right side for some reason.

````
              const requests = [
                {
                  createShape: {
                    objectId: `shape${csv.ID}`,
                    shapeType: "TEXT_BOX",
                    elementProperties: {
                      pageObjectId: `slide${index}`,
                      size: {
                        height: height,
                        width: width
                      },
                      transform: {
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        translateX: 350,
                        translateY: 100,
                        unit: "PT"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  insertText: {
                    objectId: `shape${csv.ID}`,
                    insertionIndex: 0,
                    text: csv.text
                  }
                }
              ];
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to put the value of `csv.text` to the center of the object of `shape${csv.ID}` using the method of batchUpdate in Slides API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, UpdateParagraphStyleRequest is added to the request body of `requests`.

#### Modified script:

```
const requests = [
  {
    createShape: {
      objectId: `shape${csv.ID}`,
      shapeType: "TEXT_BOX",
      elementProperties: {
        pageObjectId: `slide${index}`,
        size: {
          height: height,
          width: width
        },
        transform: {
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
          translateX: 350,
          translateY: 100,
          unit: "PT"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    insertText: {
      objectId: `shape${csv.ID}`,
      insertionIndex: 0,
      text: csv.text
    }
  },
  {
    updateParagraphStyle: {
      objectId: `shape${csv.ID}`,
      textRange: {type: "ALL"},
      style: {alignment: "CENTER"},
      fields: "alignment"
    }
  }
];
```

#### Reference:

- [UpdateParagraphStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#updateparagraphstylerequest)